# How to get outliers for all the columns in a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am working on generic function which will take dataframe and return all the outliers for every variable in a dataframe and then remove it.

```
 outliers <- function(dataframe){
   dataframe <- select_if(dataframe, is.numeric)
   for(i in 1:length(dataframe)){
   paste(names(dataframe)[i]) <- boxplot.stats(names(dataframe)[i])$out)

  }
}
```

I want to output all the outliers in respective variables and then finally remove all the outliers from dataframes.

I can remove one by one by following

```
Clean_Data[!Clean_Data$House_Price %in% boxplot.stats(Clean_Data$House_Price)$out,]
```

You can get the data from `Clean_Data = read.csv('http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Regression-Clean-Data.csv')`

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My function does not work. I want to output all the outliers for all the variables in different vectors.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Data, packages used, desired output...

Comment: I have added the data. In the output I want all numeric variables and their respective outliers  in a separate vector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We create a function by selecting only the `numeric` columns (`select_if`), loop through those columns (`map`) and subset the elements that are not outliers.  This will output as a `list` of `vector`s.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
outlierremoval <- function(dataframe){
 dataframe %>%
      select_if(is.numeric) %>% #selects on the numeric columns
      map(~ .x[!.x %in% boxplot.stats(.)$out]) #%>%
      # not clear whether we need to output as a list or data.frame
      # if it is the latter, the columns could be of different length
      # so we may use cbind.fill
      # { do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(., list(fill = NA)))}

 }

outlierremoval(Clean_Data)
```

If we want to keep all the other columns, then use `map_if` and append with NA at the end using `cbind.fill` to create a data.frame output.  But, this will also result in change of position of rows in each column based on the number of outliers

```
outlierremoval <- function(dataframe){
 dataframe %>%          
       map_if(is.numeric, ~ .x[!.x %in% boxplot.stats(.)$out]) %>%
       { do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(., list(fill = NA)))} %>%
       set_names(names(dataframe))
     


}
res <- outlierremoval(Clean_Data)
head(res)
#  X Observation Dist_Taxi Dist_Market Dist_Hospital Carpet Builtup      Parking City_Category Rainfall House_Price
#1 1           1      9796        5250         10703   1659    1961         Open         CAT B      530     6649000
#2 2           2      8294        8186         12694   1461    1752 Not Provided         CAT B      210     3982000
#3 3           3     11001       14399         16991   1340    1609 Not Provided         CAT A      720     5401000
#4 4           4      8301       11188         12289   1451    1748      Covered         CAT B      620     5373000
#5 5           5     10510       12629         13921   1770    2111 Not Provided         CAT B      450     4662000
#6 6           6      6665        5142          9972   1442    1733         Open         CAT B      760     4526000
```

#### Update

If we need to get the outliers, in the `map` step we extract the `outlier` from the `boxplot.stats`

```
outliers <- function(dataframe){
dataframe %>%
     select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
      map(~ boxplot.stats(.x)$out) 
  

  }
outliers(Clean_Data)
```

Or to replace the outliers with `NA` (which will also preserve the row positions)

```
outlierreplacement <- function(dataframe){
   dataframe %>%          
           map_if(is.numeric, ~ replace(.x, .x %in% boxplot.stats(.x)$out, NA)) %>%
           bind_cols 
         

  
}
outlierreplacement(Clean_Data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can we also output all the outliers in different vectors?

Comment: @Neil We can output it as a `list` of `vector`s.  Updated the post

Comment: @Neil BTW, when you say to remove the outliers, is to remove that observation or change it to NA?

Comment: I can remove it with `complete.cases`. Just one question what does `map` function do?

Comment: @Neil What I meant is that the first function remove the outliers resulting in `list` elements having unequal length (based on the number of outliers) and this will also resul t in  changes in row order.  The second function do the same thing, but it will append NA at the end to create the data.frame (cbind.fill).  When we do the replacement with NA, that position where the outlier was previously occupied, gets replaced with NA.  Regarding the map function, it loops through the columns and apply the function.  If we use `map_if`, applies on the numeric (is.numeric)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation.Appreciated !

Comment: Since ```rowr``` has been removed from CRAN, how can entries be filled with NAs? I tried to use the ```zoo``` package with ```do.call``` providing the same arguments above and R raised an error that ```zoo::na.fill``` is not recognised.

Comment: @Archeologist you may use `do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here' what I did on [Heart Disease UCI](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci) data

```
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("heart.csv"))
boxplot(df)
findOutliers <- function(dataframe){
  dataframe %>%Heart Disease UCI
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    map(~ boxplot.stats(.x)$out)
}
outliers <- findOutliers(df)
temp <- list()
for (col in names(outliers)) {
  outlier <- outliers[[col]]
  if (length(outlier) > 0) {
    temp[col] <- df[-which(df[[col]] %in% outlier),][col]
  } else {
    temp[col] <- df[col]
  }
}
boxplot(temp)
```

**Before removing outliers**

[image]

**After removing outliers**

[image]