# How to check for errors/outliers in large data in R?

Tags: r, validation, dataframe, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a data frame with 32 million rows. Each row is an account number with around 120 columns, mostly filled with numbers and dates.

What would be a good way to check all the columns for outliers/errors/wrong inputs efficiently?

For example I have a column with House Value. I could plot it and look for any spikes, however it takes some time to generate a plot for so many points.

Comment: How are you defining an outlier?

Comment: @BillO'Brien I am unsure. Obviously a value of one billion would be an outlier, however I don't know if 15 million is not an outlier but 70 million is. I would have to figure that out from data somehow...

Comment: This would be a perfect application for the `validate` package. There you define the rules for reasonable values and it applies to the dataset. You would still have to define what an outlier means, but it is a great package. See <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/vignettes/introduction.html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in doing this using a multidimensional measure, you can use Mahalanobis distance (M-dist). M-dist is a multidimensional way of measuring a point **P** a distance away from mean **D**. To use this you can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% mahalanobis(center = colMeans(.), cov = cov(.))
```

If you are looking to do each column independent of all other columns then you can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
outlierremoval <- function(dataframe){
 dataframe %>%
      select_if(is.numeric) %>% #selects on the numeric columns
      map(~ .x[!.x %in% boxplot.stats(.)$out]) #%>%
      # not clear whether we need to output as a list or data.frame
      # if it is the latter, the columns could be of different length
      # so we may use cbind.fill
      # { do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(., list(fill = NA)))}

 }

outlierremoval(Clean_Data)
```

This last one comes from: [How to get outliers for all the columns in a dataframe in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963595/how-to-get-outliers-for-all-the-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Re ourliers: calculate `mean` and `sd`, and then find rows where the value is larger than (say) 3 SD's away from the mean.

```
which(sd$house.value > mean(df$house.value)+3*sd(df$house.value), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

This only covers the high side of the range, though. You'll have to arbitrarily find low numbers (say, anything below six figures is probably an error).

With dates, there's two types of errors: formatting, which will result in NA when you convert it to a Date type, so that's easy; or misreported ones (e.g., 1890 instead of 1980) The only way you can find those is define a range of "reasonable" results and find those that are outside that range.