# Function/Loop to extract outliers from boxplot or car::Boxplot and tag them with ID/Name

Tags: r

Performing an explorative analysis on my dataset, I am trying to create a loop or,better, a function, to programmatically extract outliers for each variable of the database after having plotted a boxplot (base R) or a Boxplot (note the Capital B, within the car package).
Here it is a sample of the dataset at hand (in LONG format)

```
dput(head(hf.long))
structure(list(pid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217"
), class = "factor"), timewave = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    clinic = c("VIT0000015822", "VIT0000015822", "VIT0000015822", 
    "VIT0000015822", "VIT0000015822", "VIT0000017729"), lastname = c("ABATE", 
    "ABATE", "ABATE", "ABATE", "ABATE", "ABBINANTI"), firstname = c("GIUSEPPA", 
    "GIUSEPPA", "GIUSEPPA", "GIUSEPPA", "GIUSEPPA", "GIUSEPPE"
    ), age = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 76), bsa = c(1.82549041118621, 
    1.84811901382349, 1.82549041118621, 1.82549041118621, 1.82549041118621, 
    2.01198114104261), date_enroll = c("2008-05-23", "2008-11-20", 
    "2009-05-26", "2009-11-26", "2010-05-27", "2008-03-13"), 
    death = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), dev_crt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    dev_icd = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), dev_pm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    dob = c("1970-06-14", "1970-06-14", "1970-06-14", "1970-06-14", 
    "1970-06-14", "1946-01-03"), echo_avel = c(0.2, 0.39, 0.47, 
    0.51, 0.47, 0.69), echo_ealat = c(0.13, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 
    0.06), echo_eamean = c(0.085, 0.08, 0.085, 0.09, 0.085, 0.06
    ), echo_earat = c(3.7, 1.71794871794872, 1.23404255319149, 
    1.11764705882353, 1.29787234042553, 1.10144927536232), echo_easept = c(0.04, 
    0.06, 0.07, 0.06, 0.07, 0.06), echo_edect = c(173, 184, 242, 
    200, 249, 247), echo_eearat = c(8.70588235294118, 8.4, 8.4, 
    8.4, 7.17647058823529, 12.6666666666667), echo_eearat_cat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LVEDP Normal", "LVEDP Increased"
    ), class = "factor"), echo_evel = c(0.74, 0.67, 0.58, 0.57, 
    0.61, 0.76), echo_laarea = c(12, 15, 15, 15, 15, 23.6), echo_ladiam = c(3.3, 
    3.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.2, 4.4), echo_lavol = c(33, 30, 33, 33, 
    33, 93), echo_lavoli = c(18.077334067483, 16.2327208235006, 
    18.077334067483, 18.077334067483, 18.077334067483, 46.2230972760546
    ), echo_lvedd = c(51, 49, 49, 53, 51, 68), echo_lvedv = c(125, 
    103, 104, 122, 115, 197), echo_lvedv_cat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    echo_lvedvi = c(68.4747502556173, 55.7323414940188, 56.9709922126736, 
    66.8313562494825, 62.9967702351679, 97.9134426170188), echo_lvef = c(35, 
    34, 32.69, 34, 41.74, 23), echo_mr = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    echo_rap = c(5, 5, 7, 4, 10, 8.7), echo_tapse = c(17, 18, 
    19, 18, 19, 20), echo_trgrad = c(20, NA, 12.96, 16, 18.3, 
    26.95), echo_venac = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), echo_venacred = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No/Mild MR", "Moderate MR", 
    "Severe MR"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), etiol = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    height = c(175, 175, 175, 175, 175, 164), lab_album = c(3.9, 
    4.1, 3.8, 4, 3.9, 3.8), lab_bnp = c(388, 199, 387.5, 318, 
    154, 949.4), lab_bun = c(57, 47, 57, 49, 61, 52), lab_creat = c(1.2, 
    1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5), lab_crp = c(15.3, 4.5, 2.6, 4.7, 
    4.7, 2.4), lab_gfr = c(49.5075771712947, 61.1007907851606, 
    45.1394436972964, 49.5075771712947, 41.4395545039818, 46.9685685330449
    ), lab_hb = c(13.1, 13, 13.1, 13.8, 13.4, 14.9), lab_ht = c(40.4, 
    40, 40.4, 43.7, 40.9, 48), lab_microalb = c(8.9, 3.2, 3.8, 
    6.3, 2.9, 4.6), lab_ngalu = c(150, 23, 35, 25, 5, 13), lab_tni = c(0.0041, 
    0.0047, 0.003, 0.0038, 0.0037, 0.0104), race = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    rf_ckd = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), rf_ckdclass = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No CKD", "Mild (1)", "Moderate (2)", 
    "Moderate (3)", "Moderate-Severe (4)", "Severe (5)"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), rf_copd = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), rf_diab = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    rf_htn = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Females", "Males"), class = "factor"), 
    tx_acearb = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), tx_bb = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    tx_dig = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), tx_diur2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    tx_furo = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), tx_furodose = structure(c(8L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("0", "10", "10.7", "100", 
    "1000", "1075", "11", "12.5", "120", "125", "13", "150", 
    "175", "20", "200", "225", "25", "250", "275", "300", "37.5", 
    "375", "40", "425", "50", "500", "525", "575", "6.25", "60", 
    "625", "7", "75", "750", "8", "810"), class = "factor"), 
    tx_ivab = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), tx_mra = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    vit_avcond = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), vit_dbp = c(65, 65, 
    60, 50, 50, 70), vit_hr = c(56, 71, 67, 68, 66, 62), vit_nyha = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("NYHA I", "NYHA II", "NYHA III", 
    "NYHA IV"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), vit_nyhabin = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NYHA I-II", "NYHA III-IV"
    ), class = "factor"), vit_rhythm = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), vit_sbp = c(97, 
    92, 90, 95, 95, 160), weight = c(68, 70, 68, 68, 68, 95.5
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here it is the code I have come up with:

```
library(car) 
Out <- data.frame(t(sapply(names(hf.contonly), function(i)
  
{
  box <- Boxplot(hf.contonly[,i], id.method="y")
  outliers <- hf.long[box, c("lastname", "firstname", i)]
  setNames(outliers, c("Lastname", "Firstname", "Outliers"))
  
  
} )))

list1 <- unlist(Out[1, ], recursive = FALSE)  
df1  <- do.call("cbind", list)
```

where hf.contonly is a vector of just continuous variables in the dataframe
This is somewaht working, although I still need to define a second loop to Unlist each list (of lastname/firstname/variable outliers) and put that on a separate dataframe.

Anyhow, I a pretty sure this is a confused and convoluted approach to the problem and would really appreciate your insight. Searching stack, I have found the following function [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963595/how-to-get-outliers-for-all-the-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-r):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
outliers <- function(dataframe){
  dataframe %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    map(~ boxplot.stats(.x)$out)
    
 }
```

That I find at the same time elegant and efficient. Unfortunately, the function was originally created just to delete all outliers replacing them with NAs systematically and thus does not "tag" each outlier with patient name or id. I prefer to have control on the values I am going to delete and prefer to do that manually at this stage of the analysis.

Any help is as usually greatly appreciated